# GXT MessageBox with scrollable content

Tags: html, css, gwt, gxt

I have to show a stacktrace using a GXT `AlertMessageBox`, and I would like to have a fixed-size box with the content being scrollable (at least vertically).
Unfortunately I am not able to achieve that.

What I've done so far is the following :

- use an `@XTemplate` like this

  ```
  @XTemplate(value = "<pre>{stacktrace}</pre>")
  SafeHtml render(String stacktrace);
  ```

  to render the stacktrace. Here `<pre>` is needed to retain the stacktrace format.
- Use a GXT `AlertMessageBox` to render the template like this :

  ```
  MessageBox box = new AlertMessageBox("", "");
  box.setMessage(StacktraceTemplate.RENDERER.render(stackTrace).asString());
  box.setHeadingText("Stacktrace");
  box.setResize(false);
  box.setHeight(700);
  box.show();
  ```

It seems to me that I can either :

- have the container resize itself to the size of the content (if I let `box.setResize(true)`, which is the default anyway)
- have the container truncate the stacktrace to the size I specify by `box.setHeight()`

I have already tried the following :

- have the template declaring `overflow: scroll;` (i.e. `@XTemplate(value = "<pre style='overflow: scroll;'>{stacktrace}</pre>")` and also
  `@XTemplate(value = "<div style='overflow: scroll;'><pre>{stacktrace}</pre></div>")`). The result is that I see a disabled scrollbar, and
  the content is still truncated.
- wrapping the `SafeHtml` resulting from the `XTemplate` in an `HTML`, and then adding it to a `ScrollPanel`. Then I added the scrollpanel as
  the box's message this way :

  ```
  ScrollPanel container = new ScrollPanel(content);
  container.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
  HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel("");
  panel.add(container.asWidget());
  MessageBox box = new MessageBox(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<div>StackTrace</div>"),SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(panel.getElement().getInnerHTML()));
  // same setResize, setHeight, show as before
  ```

  but the result is the same (i.e. disabled scrollbar).
- wrapping in a `FlowLayoutContainer` with `getScrollSupport().setScrollMode(ScrollSupport.ScrollMode.ALWAYS);`. Same result.

What should I do to have a fixed size `MessageBox` with scrollable content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was quite near to a solution : the idea is to let the `MessageBox` adapt its size to the content, and then to fix the size of the `ScrollPanel` like this :

```
HTML content = new HTML(StacktraceTemplate.RENDERER.render(stackTrace));
ScrollPanel container = new ScrollPanel(content);
container.setHeight("700px");
HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel("");
panel.add(container.asWidget());
MessageBox box = new AlertMessageBox(
    SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<div>StackTrace</div>").asString(),
    SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(panel.getElement().getInnerHTML()).asString());
box.show();
```